# Is it safe to check file type extensions on an image hosting site

Tags: security, express, file-upload, file-type

I'm running a personal image hosting services (setup with ShareX) which is currently just limited to myself.
I'm wondering if it would be safe to check the uploaded file type to make sure it's an image or would there be another better way?

- Using express along with express-fileupload to view the contents of the image
- Only specific users can upload (isn't intended to be fully public, just close friends)

Thanks

Comment: A secure site shouldn't trust the supplied file extension or MIME type. Furthermore, malicious files can also be valid images. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gifar for example.

Comment: Okay that's good to hear, what would you suggest to solve such an issue?

Comment: Ultimately, you would have to decide what types of images you support and have some code that verifies that the contents of an uploaded file match one of your supported image file types.  For example, [jpeginfo](https://github.com/tjko/jpeginfo) can be used to test the integrity of JPEG files.